# Opening and reading a file with askopenfilename

Tags: python, tkinter

I have the following code where I'm trying to allow the user to open a text file and once the user has selected it, I would like the code to read it (this isn't a finished block of code, just to show what I'm after).

However, I'm having difficulties either using tkFileDialog.askopenfilename and adding 'mode='rb'' or using the code like below and using read where it produces an error.

Does anyone know how I can arrange to do this as I don't wish to have to type Tkinter.'module' for each item such as Menu and Listbox. Beginner to Tkinter and a bit confused! Thanks for the help!

```
import sys
from Tkinter import *
import tkFileDialog
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename # Open dialog box

fen1 = Tk()                              # Create window
fen1.title("Optimisation")               #

menu1 = Menu(fen1)

def open():

    filename = askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Text files","*.txt")])
    txt = filename.read()
    print txt
    filename.close()

fen1.mainloop()
```

Obviously the error I'm getting here is:

```
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'read'
```

I don't understand how to use the askopen and also be able to read the file I'm opening.

Comment: You may wish to start with an easier problem: can you write a Python program that opens and prints a specific file, say `/etc/passwd` or some other simple, known-to-exist, file?

Comment: I've previously worked with reading and writing text files but have never used Tkinter and am a bit confused after opening a file how it works. Would I have to strip the filename down?

Comment: FWIW the current import statement is `from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename`  if anyone needs. 10 years.... wow.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`askopenfilename` only returns a file name, what you wanted was `askopenfile` which accepts a `mode` parameter and opens the file for you.

Answer (score 9):

The `filename` in your sample code is just that -- a string indicating the name of the file you wish to open. You need to pass that to the `open()` method to return a file handle for the name. You can then read from the file handle.

Here's some quick and dirty code to run in the Python interpreter directly. (You *can* run this in a script, too, but I really like [REPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) interfaces for quickly trying things out. You may like it as well.)

```
$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 20 2012, 22:39:59) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import Tkinter
>>> from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename
>>> root = Tkinter.Tk() ; root.withdraw()
''
>>> filename = askopenfilename(parent=root)
>>> filename
'/tmp/null.c'
>>> f=open(filename)
>>> f.read()
'#include<stdio.h>\n\nint main()\n{\n  for(;NULL;)\n    printf("STACK");\n\n  return 0;\n}\n\n'
>>> f.close()
>>>
```

Note especially that there's nothing Tkinter-specific in reading the file -- the dialog box just gives you a filename.

Comment: is that possible that I can able to browse the files of remote machine through `askopenfilename` or other command

Answer (score 0):

Your error is the name of your function. I simply changed `def open()` for `def open1()` and it works.

```
def open1():

    filename = askopenfilename(parent=fen1)
    print(filename)
    f = open(filename)
    txt = f.read()
    print txt
    f.close()
```

Comment: "open" is not called by the open function in the original question.  In your example it appears you would have defined a recursive function, but where did your function come from?

Answer (score 0):

i think you can read your file like this

```
import sys
from Tkinter import *
import tkFileDialog
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename # Open dialog box

fen1 = Tk()                              # Create window
fen1.title("Optimisation")               #

menu1 = Menu(fen1)
def open1():

    filename = askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Text files","*.txt")])
    text1 = open(filename, r)
    read_file = text1.read()
    print(read_file)
    text1.close()

fen1.mainloop()
```

Comment: just a small correction:  text1 = open(filename, "r")