# Tkinter cant open file up using askopenfilenames

Tags: python, tkinter

I am using

```
root = Tk()
root.geometry('1000x500')
root.title("Permutations and Combinations Lesson")
app = Questionnaire(root)
root.mainloop() 
filez = tkFileDialog.askopenfilenames(parent=root,title='PandC.mp4')
print(filez)
```

but I cannot get the video to open up and play, does anyone know the reason for this? thanks

Comment: Hey, do you really think that it will magically load the file and play it for you?? You'll have to implement this yourself. `askopenfilenames` simply brings the dialog where you choose files, that's all

Comment: @ForceBru honestly yes thats what I thought, sorry

Comment: here's a link to an answer to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10993362/4354477

Comment: code after calling `mainloop` won't run until you destroy the window. This is fundamental to how tkinter works. Also, you can't call `askopenfilenames` after you've destroyed the root window.

Answer (score 0):

It's not going to open it for you. It just returns the filename path if one is selected, otherwise it returns `None`.

You can use `os.startfile(path)` to open / start it, or `askopenfile`