# How to open a exe file using python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to open a exe file from C drive by clicking a button from my GUI and up till now i am unable to select the specific file. Can i know if there is any function to directly open the file in Tkinter. Currently,tkFileDialog.askdirectory only direct me to the FILES.

```
import Tkinter
import tkMessageBox
import tkFileDialog
import os
import subprocess

top = Tkinter.Tk()

def run():
File = tkFileDialog.askdirectory()
os.system(File)

b = Tkinter.Button(top, text = 'DAQoutput', command= run)
b.pack()

top.mainloop()
```

Comment: try using `os.system(r'PATH_TO_EXE')`

Comment: `askdirectory` is for selecting directories, not files.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the stupid question but is there any function to open the file through searching the directory? I read up about py2exe function but wasnt sure whether it can help to open the exe file.

Comment: This is not really a tkinter question. The subprocess module gives gives more options for running a external program than os.system.

Answer (score 0):

Directly using Tkinter?  No there is no command for it  but you don't need one.  Tkinter is a GUI toolkit and that's all it does.

Instead use `os.system()` to launch your exe.

Your script should look something like this:

```
import Tkinter
import tkMessageBox
import tkFileDialog
import os

top = Tkinter.Tk()

def run(self):
    File = tkFileDialog.askdirectory()
    os.system(File)

b = Tkinter.Button(top, text = 'DAQoutput', command= self.run)
b.pack()

top.mainloop()
```

Comment: Also if you get any errors please leave a comment mentioning what they are.  My version of Python cannot run the above script so I may need to edit my answer if it runs incorrectly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i get a NameError that says the name 'run' is not defined. I tried define the class but to no avail.

Comment: @Gavin123  Sorry about that, I edited the script and it should now work.  If it does not, once again leave a comment and I will do my best.  Also I think that the only really important part is the `File = tkFileDialog.askdirectory()` and `os.system(File)` and using your knowledge of Tkinter you should be able to make a button trigger this action anyway.  Oh and the error on my script  occurred because the def function needs to be put before the actual button, but you were right to define the class.  That needed doing as well.

Comment: Hi, according to your edited script, i still get a name error that says the name "self" is not defined. I try editing the script but i am still only able to view the directory and not selecting the files that i want to open(which is the main function i wanted). So please advise. Thanks!

Comment: `root.filename = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/",title = "Select file",filetypes = (("exe files","*.exe"),("all files","*.*")))`.  I got this snippet [here](https://pythonspot.com/en/tk-file-dialogs/).   From what I understand we have both specified for opening a dictionary! This should be it. Also I'd love it if you could tell me where I went wrong.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10993089/opening-and-reading-a-file-with-askopenfilename) might be useful as well

Comment: Hi, i didnt make use of the method you suggested. I tried out another method and it work out fine. Hope it can help you too!

Comment: import Tkinter
import tkMessageBox
import tkFileDialog
import os
import sys
top = Tkinter.Tk()

def openfile():
    try:
        os.startfile(''EXACT FILE LOCATION'')

    except Exception, e:
        print str(e)
        
b = Tkinter.Button(top, text = 'DAQoutput', command= openfile)
b.pack()

top.mainloop()

Comment: I am pleased you have your answer sorry I could not help much.  If you want I can delete this answer because it seems you did most of the work on it and it did not help much anyway.  Also if you want you can put what you said up above as an accepted answer and if it is up-voted you will get an increased reputation and it will help those who are also looking for the answer to the same problem. ; )

Comment: @Gavin123  Sorry I don't think you have read the above - I forgot to ping.